# Create generic function from a generic interface's type

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to create a generic function that uses the type defined by the return of a different generic function.  I have a function that returns the first generic interface, something like:

```
myFunction( request: MyThing ): SpecialInterface<YourThing>
```

So I make my new interface with that wants to use `YourThing` and I can get the return using the ReturnType helper

```
coolFunction( request: ReturnType<myFunctionType> ): void;
```

and that gives me the generic interface that the other function returns, but I don't want `SpecialInterface<YourThing>` I want `YourThing`, the type the generic is using here.

Is there a way to get that type?

Comment: The answer depends on how `SpecialInterface<T>` is defined.  You *might* be able to do it with `ReturnType<myFunctionType> extends SpecialInterface<infer T> ? T : never`, but whether that works as expected really depends on information not presented here.  Could you edit the question into a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that resolves the type of `request` to `YourThing`.

```
interface MyThing { 
    y: string;
}

interface YourThing { 
    x: string;
}

interface SpecialInterface<T> { 
    z: T;
}

const myFunction = (request: MyThing): SpecialInterface<YourThing> => {
    return null;
};

type InnerType<T> = T extends SpecialInterface<infer X> ? X : never;

const coolFunction = (request: InnerType<ReturnType<typeof myFunction>>): void => { 
    // do something
}

coolFunction({}); // error
coolFunction({} as MyThing); // error
coolFunction({} as YourThing);
```

Here it is [in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyThing%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20YourThing%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SpecialInterface%3CT%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20z%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myFunction%20%3D%20(request%3A%20MyThing)%3A%20SpecialInterface%3CYourThing%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20InnerType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20SpecialInterface%3Cinfer%20X%3E%20%3F%20X%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20coolFunction%20%3D%20(request%3A%20InnerType%3CReturnType%3Ctypeof%20myFunction%3E%3E)%3A%20void%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AcoolFunction(%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0AcoolFunction(%7B%7D%20as%20MyThing)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0AcoolFunction(%7B%7D%20as%20YourThing)%3B%0D%0A).

Comment: This does seem to work, but note that the classes here are all empty and not [structurally distinct](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) .  In particular, `SpecialInterface<T>` [doesn't depend structurally on `T`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  This can lead to weirdness (e.g., `coolFunction({})`, `coolFunction(new MyThing())`, `coolFunction(new SpecialInterface<string>())` all compile with no error).

Comment: Good point @jcalz. I updated the answer to make `MyThing` and `YourThing` structurally distinct.

Comment: Ideally you'd also add something to `SpecialInterface<T>` so that it is also not empty and so that it depends on `T`.  e.g., (`interface SpecialInterface<T> {specialProperty: T}`)

Comment: @jcalz I am still not understanding, within the scope of this question, why it's important to have `SpecialInterface<T>` be structurally dependent on `T`. Can you elaborate its importance here.

Comment: If `SpecialInterface<T>` isn't structurally dependent on `T`, then any inference can happen. `SpecialInterface<string>` and `SpecialInterface<number>` are the same type, namely `{}`.  And trying to infer `string` or `number` from `{}` is not possible in general. There's something happening that makes it work for you here, but I can't find any documentation that says you can count on such fortuitous inference. The [FAQ entry linked above](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) (and the one that follows it) explain the issue.

Comment: > "In general, you should *never* have a type parameter which is unused. The type will have unexpected compatibility and will also fail to have proper generic type inference in function calls."

Comment: Thanks for those details. The behavior surprises me too. A related surprise is that it does not work to use `interface AnyGeneric<T> {}` in the conditional type like this
`type InnerType<T> = T extends AnyGeneric<infer X> ? X : never`. If we use that, then the `request` is always resolved to `{}`. There seems to be something more than structural typing happening here.

Comment: @jcalz I spoke with a member of the TypeScript team. The reason that the compiler did not see `AnyGeneric<T>` and `SpecialInterface<T>` as the same structural type (when both were empty) is a compiler optimization that uses the type name (kinda) instead of the type structure and which, as you expressed, is not guaranteed to always work. It makes the compiler seem to do nominal typing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost all the way there, we just need to access that field:

```
function coolFunction(request: (ReturnType<typeof myFunction>)['whatThing']): void {
```

More complete example, for context:

```
interface SpecialInterface<T> {
    whatThing: T;
}

interface YourThing {
    foo: string;
}

interface MyThing {
    bar: string;
}

function myFunction(request: MyThing): SpecialInterface<YourThing> {
    return { whatThing: { foo: "hi" } };
}

type myFunctionType = (ReturnType<typeof myFunction>);

function coolFunction(request: myFunctionType['whatThing']): void {
    // Do something with request, which is of type YourThing!
    console.log(request.foo);
}
```